# Add a negative symbol to a numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server, numeric, varchar, negative-number

Using SQL 2014 I need to append a negative sign to a list of numeric values. The data are dollar amounts with numerous places behind the decimal point. I did convert the data to numeric(15, 2)

Here is my select statement.

```
SELECT '-' + convert(15,2), MONEY from TABLE
```

I am getting the error: Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

I tried converting to varchar as well.

```
select '-' + CONVERT(varchar10), (convert(numeric(15, 2), MONEY)) from
TABLE
```

I get the same error as above. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not store a negative number?

Comment: Your syntax doesn't make sense.

Comment: As posted your query would not return that error because the syntax is horribly wrong all over the place. This is probably a good place for you to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT -convert(MONEY, 15.2) from TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

How about multiplying by -1 instead?  Something like this:

```
SELECT -1 * convert(MONEY, 15.2) from TABLE
```

Your syntax isn't correct.  I am guessing you want something like the above.

Or subtract from 0.

Answer (score 0):

why not trying Cast Function

```
SELECT -1 * CAST(MONEY  as Numeric(15.2)) from TABLE
```